# Alternative to registerDataSetObserver() in RecyclerView

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

In listView, to listen to changes in the Adapter data set, i use

```
adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                super.onChanged();

            }
        });
```

But i am uanble to find a function that does the similar job in a RecyclerView. How can it be achieved in  case of RecyclerView.Adapter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [`registerAdapterDataObserver()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#registerAdapterDataObserver(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver)) instead.

Sample usage:

```
mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(myObserver);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the only callbacks that get triggered inside the `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` are a result of which notify methods you call.  So for instance if you call `notifyItemInserted()` after you add an item to your adapter then `onItemRangeInserted()` will get called.

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira Then how do you access the registerAdapterDataObserver's override methods like onChanged()?  Would this work "myObserver = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver { ..."?

Comment: Yes. Just create a `myObserver` which is an implementation of `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver`